# Is it possible to add a button to a sharepoint event for power automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Pretty much the title....basically I want to have events posted to sharepoint. When people view the event I would like to have a button to RSVP. If they click it, it would run a flow. The flow will create an item in another list with the logged in user ID and perform some other logic.

My only thought at the moment is include a hyperlink in the event that when clicked it is caught by the "http response" trigger in power automate. But that requires a premium license which I'd prefer to avoid for this simple task.

Thanks